# get-mailbox across domains exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-server-2007

**When I ran command below it works predictably**

```
get-mailbox -identity xxx.xxx@domain .com
```

when I try to ran the same command in a script it keep getting errors could not be found on domain controller

> $users = Import-Csv "C:\Users\xx\Documents\CSV\PORB.csv"   foreach
>   ($user in $users) {
>       $Recipients = Get-Mailbox -Identity $user.users   [array]$AllEmailAddresses = $Recipient.EmailAddresses
>   [array]$NoX500Addresses = $Recipient.EmailAddresses | Where {$_
>   -notlike "X500:*"} Set-Mailbox -Identity $Recipient.Identity -EmailAddresses $NoX500Addresses

**Error I get: Get-Mailbox : The operation could not be performed because object 'd.j@domain.com' could not be found on domain controller
'XXX.aaa.bbbb.ccc.net'.
At line:5 char:19
+     $Recipients = Get-Mailbox -Identity $user.users }**

**I am not sure what I am doing wrong I also included ** `$AdminSessionADSettings.ViewEntireForest = $true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found another Script on the web to get domain list and act on each domain in the list**

> > $objForest = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
> >     $DomainList = @($objForest.Domains | Select-Object Name) $Domains =
> >     $DomainList | foreach {$_.Name}
>
> ## Act on each domain
>
> foreach($Domain in ($Domains)){ $users = Import-Csv "C:\Users\ramer\Documents\CSV\PORB.csv" foreach ($user in
>   $users) { $Recipients = Get-Mailbox -Identity $user.users 
>   [array]$AllEmailAddresses = $Recipient.EmailAddresses 
>   [array]$NoX500Addresses = $Recipient.EmailAddresses | Where {$_
>   -notlike "X500:*"}  Set-Mailbox -Identity $Recipient.Identity -EmailAddresses $NoX500Addresses}